# How to optimize a rest API parameter inside the request query, so that the response data match with a pre-defined desired output?

Tags: python, here-api, mathematical-optimization

I use a rest API (HERE) that I insert a set of coordinates in the request (origin, destination) as well as some values of another parameter called `SpeedFcCat`. The number of values that describe `SpeedFcCat` in the request are 8.

The API then returns a JSON file out of which I extract the speed profile that the vehicle followed according to the API algorithm. Since I have the actual, recorded speed profile that the vehicle followed in reality, I am able to compare the two speed profiles (`Real_speeed`, `API_speed`). So, after the request, I end up having a dataframe as the one below:

| Real_Speed | API_Speed |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | 22 |
| 40 | 31 |
| 66 | 58 |
| 64 | 69 |
| 75 | 70 |
| 81 | 76 |
| 76 | 84 |
| 55 | 63 |

The 8 values of `SpeedFcCat` in the API request determine the speed profile that the API will return. What I want to do, is write a program that automatically calibrates these 8 values in a way that values in column `Real_Speed` best match the values in `API_speed`.

So far, I've tried to calibrate `SpeedFcCat` so that I end up with the absolute difference between the average `Real_Speed` and `API_Speed` to not exceed a treshold let's say 5.
What I do now is this:

```
initial_SpeedFcCat = "80,77,70,63,55,49,45,30"
params = {
        'waypoint0': "48.22696,6.431135",
        'waypoint1': "46.19643,-0.07133",
        "SpeedFcCat": initial_SpeedFcCat,
        "apiKey": some_key,
}
response = requests.post(url=url, params=params)
data = resp.json()
```

Here I write code to process the JSON file, get the `API_speed`, and make the dataframe as above. Then I do this:

```
avg_real_speed = df["Real_Speed"].mean()
avg_API_speed = df["API_Speed"].mean()
step = 0.025

while abs(avg_real_speed - avg_API_speed) > treshold:

    sign = 1 if avg_API_speed < avg_real_speed else -1
    speedFcCat_new *= step
    params = {
        'waypoint0': "48.22696,6.431135",
        'waypoint1': "46.19643,-0.07133",
        "SpeedFcCat": speedFcCat_new,
        "apiKey": some_key,
                            }
    response = requests.post(url=url, params=params)
    data = resp.json()
```

Then I get the updated JSON file, extract again the `API_speed`, calculate `avg_API_speed`, and continue inside the while loop

With this code I manage to somehow converge to the `SpeedFcCat` values that satisfy the while loop if the treshold is not strict. However, this doesn't make necessarily the two profiles very similar. In one case the average can be achieved by a very smooth profile let's say `avg_speed = 60` where all speed values are between 50 and 70 and in the other, the same avg might be achieved with a very transient profile where speeds vary between 20 and 120.

Therefore, I am trying to find a solution to calibrate and optimize `SpeedFcCat` values in a way so that I will end up with similar avg_real_speed and `avg_API_speed` **but also similar variance**. To succeed on that, the values of `SpeedFcCat` must be updated with different weights and not with the same step as I do now.